# How to post formdata and get using Reactjs and Php

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs(Nextjs) and php, I want to send formdata with axios and want to get in php
but right now i am unable to get any parameter at api side,How can i fix this ? Here is my current code

```
const handleSubmit = async(e: any) => {
        const formData = new FormData(); 
              formData.append("title", "test"); // for testing passing static value
               data.append('avatar', file);
            const response = await axios({
              method: "post",
              url: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/",
              data: formData,
              headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
              }).then(function (response) {
                alert('respone is '+ response.data.msg);
                console.log("success");
                console.log(response.msg);
               
            }).catch(function (error) {
               alert('respone is '+ error);
                console.log("failed to get recommend playlist");
                console.log('error is '+ error.msg);
            });

 }

 <form className="forms-sample" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<input type="file" onChange={handleFileSelect}/>
<input type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" placeholder="Title" name="name" value={state.name} onChange={handleChange}/>
<form>
```

And In php i am using following code but not working ( in console/network api path is correct),How can i get text and input file ? (upload file)

```
public function test3()
    {
                        $mydata=file_get_contents("php://input");
                        echo "title is ".$mydata['title'];
       

             
    }
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php: _"`php://input` is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`."_

Answer (score 0):

When using `multipart/form-data` enctype to post data you should get the data from the global `$_POST` variable.

If using a PHP framework, there is usually a Request object that holds this data and implements method for accessing it.

Check this for reference:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php